I need to change also a cell with the same value as the sheet name excel
I wrote this code to create sheets taking the name from a range, i need to also change a specific cell in the new sheet with the same name of the created sheet
    function main(wb: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
        // Define constants.
        const LOOKUP_SHEET_NAME: string = "JP PPS";
        const LOOKUP_RANGE_ADDRESS: string = "P4:P12";
        const TEMPLATE_SHEET_NAME: string = "Template";
        // Return the values of the lookup range in an array.
        let lws = wb.getWorksheet(LOOKUP_SHEET_NAME);
        let lrg = lws.getRange(LOOKUP_RANGE_ADDRESS);
        let lData = lrg.getValues();
        // Referemce the template.
        let tws = wb.getWorksheet(TEMPLATE_SHEET_NAME);
        // Use each value in the array as a name for a copy
        // of the template created after the last worksheet.
        for (let i = 0; i < lData.length; i++) {
            let nws = tws.copy(ExcelScript.WorksheetPositionType //
                .after, wb.getLastWorksheet());
            let nwsName: string = lData[i].toString();
            nws.setName(nwsName);
        };
    }



lData is a 2D array, where lData[i] represents a sub-array, and lData[i][0] is an individual element within the 2D array.

Retrieve the value as a String using lrg.getTexts(), eliminating the need for .toString() in your script.

It is highly recommended to check if a sheet with the desired name already exists; otherwise, the line of code that renames the sheet after creation will cause an error.


function main(wb: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    // Define constants.
    const LOOKUP_SHEET_NAME: string = "JP PPS";
    const LOOKUP_RANGE_ADDRESS: string = "P4:P12";
    const TEMPLATE_SHEET_NAME: string = "Template";
    // Return the values of the lookup range in an array.
    let lws = wb.getWorksheet(LOOKUP_SHEET_NAME);
    let lrg = lws.getRange(LOOKUP_RANGE_ADDRESS);
    let lData = lrg.getTexts();
    // Referemce the template.
    let tws = wb.getWorksheet(TEMPLATE_SHEET_NAME);
    // get the list of all sheets' name
    const sheetsList = wb.getWorksheets().map(sht => sht.getName());
    // Use each value in the array as a name for a copy
    // of the template created after the last worksheet.
    const TARGET_REF: string = "A1" // modify as needed
    for (let i = 0; i < lData.length; i++) {
        let nwsName: string = lData[i][0];
        if (nwsName.length) {  // skip blank cell
            if (sheetsList.includes(nwsName)) { // remove existing sheet
                wb.getWorksheet(nwsName).delete();
            }
            let nws = tws.copy(ExcelScript.WorksheetPositionType.after
                , wb.getLastWorksheet());
            nws.setName(nwsName);
            nws.getRange(TARGET_REF).setValue(nwsName); // write sheet name to A1
        }
    };
}

Microsoft documentation:

ExcelScript.Range interface getText()


I get an error saying that i can't perform that operation

Please share all output in console.

I get worker.js:8 Uncaught (in promise) {message: 'You cannot perform the requested operation.', code: 'AccessDenied', type: 'Range', method: 'setValue', line: 26}

Is Template sheet protected?

I fixed by unprotecting the specific cell, but if i add it to the worksheet as a button it just get an error on line 8, is unable to read getRange

Sheet JP PPS may not exist in the workbook.

Is working if i run the script manually, but not with the button

I've tested it (run by clicking button) without issue.

Then i do not know what could be wrong

I've tried other scripts, also my previous one and it works via button

Try to change sheet name from JP PPS to JPPPS, and update script. Then re-create button.

I've just created a new script and copy pasted the code and it worked, Thank you

Good news.
What should I do when someone answers my question?

I've added a constant SPECIFIC_CELL_ADDRESS that defines the specific cell where you want to place the name of the new sheet. You can change "A1" to any other cell address as needed.
After renaming the new worksheet, nws.getRange(SPECIFIC_CELL_ADDRESS).setValue(nwsName); sets the value of that specific cell to the name of the new sheet.
function main(wb: ExcelScript.Workbook) {  
// Define constants.  
const LOOKUP_SHEET_NAME: string = "JP PPS";  
const LOOKUP_RANGE_ADDRESS: string = "P4:P12";  
const TEMPLATE_SHEET_NAME: string = "Template";  
const SPECIFIC_CELL_ADDRESS: string = "A1"; // Change this to your desired cell address  

// Return the values of the lookup range in an array.  
let lws = wb.getWorksheet(LOOKUP_SHEET_NAME);  
let lrg = lws.getRange(LOOKUP_RANGE_ADDRESS);  
let lData = lrg.getValues();  

// Reference the template.  
let tws = wb.getWorksheet(TEMPLATE_SHEET_NAME);  

// Use each value in the array as a name for a copy of the template created after the last worksheet.  
for (let i = 0; i < lData.length; i++) {  
    let nws = tws.copy(ExcelScript.WorksheetPositionType.After, wb.getLastWorksheet());  
    let nwsName: string = lData[i].toString();  
    nws.setName(nwsName);  

    // Set a specific cell in the new sheet to its name  
    nws.getRange(SPECIFIC_CELL_ADDRESS).setValue(nwsName);  
}  
}

